# Customizable form doesn't show

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I've made customizable form but it doesn't show on the page. It is my first time using silverstripe and I couldn't understand from the documentation which is even the entry file. Don't really know what should I write as here because I don't have code at all. Can only show the form as image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put a `$Form` tag in your template (probably Page.ss) where you want the form to appear.